# ui-g, ui-md-2 not working in angular 10 project

Tags: angular, primeng

I've migrated this project from angular5 to angular10 but classes like ui-g not working in it. I've installed primefacesv10.0.0, yet they're not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you and guide you through

[migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide)

Basically all 'ui-' classes become 'p-'